# Inquiry on example of explicit join in the SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have following sparql query(from the book, semantic web primer):

```
select ?n
where
{
    ?x rdf:type uni:Course;
        uni:isTaughtBy :949352
    ?c uni:name ?n .
    FILTER(?c=?x) .
}
```

In this case, I guess this code is same as the the following:

```
Select ?n
Where
{
    ?x rdf:type uni:course;
        uni:isTaughtBy :949352 .
    ?x uni:name ?n .
}
```

Does this query lead to coding error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't see why it should give you an error or produce wrong results. Just make sure to always use the right case (`uni:Course` vs. `uni:course`), as SPARQL is case sensitive.

To be honest, the first version seems rather obscure as it uses a `FILTER` without a real need for it. That said, you may further slim down your query if you wish:

```
SELECT ?n
WHERE
{
    ?x rdf:type uni:Course;
       uni:isTaughtBy :949352;
       uni:name ?n .
}
```

However, keep in mind that saving characters does not always lead to improved readability.

Comment: Happy to help. Another improvement: You might try using `SELECT DISTINCT` to get a list without possible duplicates. Also, if you find my answer useful, you might consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

For your example yes the queries are identical and there would be no value in using a `FILTER` over a join.

---

However the reason why you might use the `FILTER` form is the difference in semantics between joins and the `=` operator

Joins require that the values of the variables be exactly the same RDF term, whereas `=` does value equality - do the values of RDF terms that represent the same value?  This is primarily a concern when one/both of the values may have literal values

It's easier to see if you take a specific example, assume `?x=4` and `?c = 4.0` (which is a bad example for your query but illustrates the point)

`?x = ?c` would give `true` while a join would give no results because they are not the exact same term